# \pause doesn't work in beamer

Tags: beamer

Good evening,

I encounter problems with the `\pause` command in `beamer`. There is not any pause that work in the pdf resulting file and I do not understand why. If any could help me, thanks. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}% [handout] supprime la barre de navigation en bas à droite.

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{Paramertic free form shape optimization for electromagnetism problem}
\author{Pierre Bonnelie}
\institute{Université de Limoges}
\date{June, 10th 2013}

% Sommaire automatique
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sommaire}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections, pausesubsections]
  \end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} % Pause entre chaque \item de itemize.

    % Page de titre
    \begin{frame}
      \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    % Sommaire
    \begin{frame}
      \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{Optimal trajectoy problem}

    \begin{frame}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item ahaha
          \pause
        \item aaahhaha
      \end{itemize}
      \end{frame}


      \begin{frame}
        Voici ma première idée, je cause, je cause...
        \pause
        Voici la deuxième idée que j'affiche 
        quand     je suis prête à en causer.
        \pause
        Voici la troisième idée après réflexion.
      \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Optimal trajectory problem}      
      \begin{itemize}
        \item test 1
          \pause
        \item Vector field
          $$\begin{array}{ccccc}
               v & : & \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 & \to & T\mathbb{R}^2\\
               \end{array}$$
          \pause
          \item Objective function
            $$\begin{array}{ccccc}
                 F & : & \mathcal{B}_{N,D} \times \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^2,T\mathbb{R}^2) & \to & \mathbb{R}_+ \\
                   &   &     (\gamma,v)  & \mapsto & F(\gamma,v)\\
          \end{array}$$
            \pause
            \item Minimization problem
              \[ min ... \]
      \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Un exemple de titre}
      \framesubtitle{avec un exemple de sous-titre}
      Enfin, le texte ! :)
    \end{frame}

    \section{Shape optimization problem}
\end{document}
```

I compile with pdflatex `file.tex` but all the pauses does not work at all.

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 25):

Of course they don't work; you are in `handout` mode, and for a handout the effect of pauses is obviously deactivated; replace

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

with

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Comment: Short and effective. Love this!

Comment: Derp. I just ran into this problem. I hadn't realized that the file I had copied and started working from was a handout. From now on I am going to put some handout-only content in, saying it is a handout.

Comment: It follows that `handout` mode can be used as a dev/prod switch: hide all pauses when working on a document and turn them on only before showing them to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent presentation, the `\pause` command was working on all slides but one. It turned out I was using the `shrink` option with the wrong syntax. I had written:

```
\begin{frame}[10]
```

Instead of:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink = 10]
```

Once I fixed the `shrink` code, the `\pause` commands on the slide all started working again.